# postgresql: Creating Database and User first time : multiple options

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a database and a user for my project

```
# sudo su - postgres
# psql
```

Method 1:

```
CREATE DATABASE myproject;
CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;
```

Method 2:

```
CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE DATABASE myproject OWNER myprojectuser
```

So which is the right way

Answer (score 1):

First you create USER/ROLE:

```
CREATE ROLE myprojectuser createdb login password 'password';
```

After you've done that, you can check all users using command `\du`

Then CREATE DATABSE:

```
CREATE DATABASE myproject OWNER myprojectuser;
```

After you've created database,you can connect to your database as myprojectuser using:

```
\c myproject myprojectuser localhost
```